# Copy-Paste macro works differently depending on active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to write an Excel macro to find the last column with data, copy that column, then paste in the next (empty) column. My problem is, there are multiple sheets, and it only works up to the currently active sheet...After that, it doesn't work correctly:

`Dim lcol as Long`

`For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count`

Step 1 - Get last column with data in row 6

`lCol = Cells(6, Worksheets(j).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Step 2 - Copy that column to the next column

`Worksheets(j).Columns(lCol).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(j).Columns(lCol + 1)`

Step 3- Change the value of row 6 in the new column to be 1+ the value of same cell in copied column

`Worksheets(j).Cells(6, lCol + 1) = Worksheets(j).Cells(6, lCol) + 1`

`Next j`

If I have 5 tabs/sheets in the workbook, and my active tab is the last one, all sheets get processed correctly. If my active tab is, say, the 3rd one, all sheets up to that tab get processed correctly, but the sheets after that don't.

Anyone know why this is or what I need to do to make sure all sheets get processed regardless of which is active?

Comment: Your problem is in Step 1. You haven't qualified the `Worksheet` that the `Cells` are on, so there's an implicit reference to the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thanks, I had to look that up ("qualifying" references) but that did the trick.

Comment: Great! It's best practice to fully qualify any `Range` or `Cells` calls  with the `Workbook` and `Worksheet` they belong to. Fixing that makes your code much more robust.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)